# Use of the hat (^) character in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript

I am confused by the use of the hat character (^) in the following code, which has been lifted from [reagent-phonecat](https://github.com/vvvvalvalval/reagent-phonecat).

```
^{:key phone} [phone-component phone]
```

`phone-component` is itself a function (but not being invoked as it is in a vector) and `phone` will be a map with keys such as `:battery`.

My [research](https://yobriefca.se/blog/2014/05/19/the-weird-and-wonderful-characters-of-clojure/) says that the `^` indicates metadata or a type hint, but doesn't help!

Here's the file: [core.cljs](https://github.com/vvvvalvalval/reagent-phonecat/blob/master/src/cljs/reagent_phonecat/core.cljs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you understand what `key` does in react since reagent just passes it along to React:

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children

> [...] you can uniquely identify each child by assigning it a key:
>
> [...]
>
> When React reconciles the keyed children, it will ensure that any child with key will be reordered (instead of clobbered) or destroyed (instead of reused).

Next, the `^{...}` construct is just clojure attaching meta data to the next **form**:

http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters

Note: It's **not** a type hint in this example. That would require a `:tag` meta data key.

The next form in this case is a simple vector `[..]` where your first elements is a reference to the component that you want to (eventually) call.

Reagent takes the data structure (the nested vectors) and will generate virtual DOM elements from it passing it to react. It will also call the nested component.

So reagent will read the meta data of each vector that you return and pass along any `:key` that you specified to react. This simply so that react can identify the elements in each re-render.

Thus, in your case the `phone` will end be passed on to react as the key. Note that the key will end up as a string in the DOM attribute of the react element. So it's best to pass in a string that's not too long so as to not clutter your DOM attributes.

Comment: So React will be using the whole phone map i.e. {:battery: ...} as the key? (avoiding the time it would take the programmer to work out a key, needing to ask herself questions like 'do some phones have the same name?').

Comment: Yes, but it's usually better to make it explicitly a (shortish) string since it'll end up in the DOM as an attribute

Answer (score -1):

After going through the file, I could make out that phone-component is a macro for a function.

This macro can be used to call the function. Macro accepts phone key as input and returns the details about the phone.

Link may be of some help
http://java.ociweb.com/mark/clojure/article.html

Comment: `defn` is a macro yes. Excuse my loose wording calling it a 'function'.